# What is the double integral of $e^{y^3}dydx$

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^3 \int_1^{\sqrt{x/3}} e^{y^3}\,dy\,dx$$

I switched the order of integration to:

$$ \int_1^{3y^2} \int_0^3 e^{y^3} \,dx\,dy $$

I evaluated the integral but now I am stuck with:

$$\int_1^{3y^2} 3e^{y^3}\, dy $$

and I am not sure how to integrate this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. Draw a figure showing the integration region. Change the order of integration. You obtain the double integral $$\int_{1}^{0}\int_{0}^{3y^2}e^{y^3}dxdy=-\int_{0}^{1}3y^2e^{y^3}dy=e^{y^3}\rvert_{0}^{1}=\color\red {1-e}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was only that you got the bounds mixed up. It should actually be

$$ \int_0^3 \int_1^{3y^2} e^{3y^2}\,dx\,dy $$